# OpenGL ES 2D scene, multiple scene graph trees for different elements

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es, 2d, game-engine

Within my OpenGL ES project I am debating whether to create a scene graph for my GUI and a separate one for my actors. This will allow me to control the GUI system and transform it without effecting the scene and vice versa.

However, I am wondering, if this will have implications on speed or if this is generally not a good idea.

Are there any approach or design philosophies that I should be considering at this stage?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't your GUI and actors be sibling nodes in the same scene graph?

As long as they have separate transforms, you can control them independently of each other.

Comment: This is true, but by doing that, if I change the root node in any way, it effects everything. This means that I have to consider global scaling system that applies to not only the actors, but the GUI. It seems strange for me to apply this "transform space" to things external to the GUI. 

Yes, they can be changed independently, but aren't we making it harder to manage scenes and entity instances?

Comment: I don't get it. Simply consider the actor node to be your "root node" and you're fine. What's the problem? And if you're drawing your GUI using OpenGL, then it's not "strange", is it? Think about how easy it'll be to have a "full screen" mode (by applying a different scaling to your "main window").

Comment: Fair enough, you make a good point. Just looking for other concepts and ideas, exploring possibilities. Thanks for the input Rahul.